# Javascript onchange event blocked when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have an input field, which is used to perform some calculations. There are 2 buttons that the user can click to indicate which set of calculations they would like to perform. However, in case the user does not click either button, I want a default action to be performed:

```js
function button1Clicked() {
    alert('button 1 clicked');
}
function button2Clicked() {
    alert('button 2 clicked');
}
function noButtonClicked() {
    alert('no button was clicked');
}
```

My fields look something like this:

```html
<input type="text" id="inpt1" onchange="noButtonClicked();" />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="button1Clicked();" />
<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="button2Clicked();" />
```

I can get the action from the buttons to execute as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371961/button-onclick-doesnt-fire-after-onchange-input-field-when-user-immediately-cli), but it's not reliable. Is there a simpler solution to blocking the onchange event from firing when one of these buttons is clicked?

**To Clarify**: When the user is done editing the input field, if neither button is clicked, then execute `noButtonClicked()`. If one of the buttons is clicked, then execute the function associated with the button, but not the `noButtonClicked()` function.

Comment: `preventDefault` on the event?

Comment: I don't get the question 100% but you have messed-up the function names

Comment: I'm with Ted. You mistyped the function names. Aside that, I don't understand what your code is NOT doing. I see a change event on the text field, and click listeners on the others. None of those should interfere unless your click listeners are modifying the value of the text field. You do not specify this in your question

Comment: Typo fixed. Basically, I want only 1 of the 3 functions to fire - but I can't seem to block the firing of the onchange event when one of the two buttons is clicked, since it seems to execute first. And yes, all 3 buttons make modifications to values on the screen that would interfere with one another.

Comment: Have you tried onkeyup instead of onchange? - unless this could be a long value. That would fire every key stroke.

Comment: The issue is that I don't want the onchange() to execute at all if one of the buttons is clicked, but if the user clicks anywhere else, or tabs out of the field, then I want the onchange() function to run. However, it seems that the onchange(), blur(), etc is executing first.

Comment: This is little odd, you need to wait for certian time and see if user is clickign either btn1 or btn2 with in that time frame, if user did not click either of those buttons with in that time frame then you can fire the 3rd function, for that you may need to start timign on textbox blur event.

Comment: @HaBo That was the solution presented in the question I linked to - but it isn't very reliable, unfortunately. I was hoping there was a better way to do this than relying on a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I understand your issue now. You have no way of interrupting the blur event. This is axiomatic, unfortunately. Here is a tested solution that is essentially no different than the answer you linked to except a mild difference in structure...

```
var queue = null;

function checkInput(elem){
    if(elem.id == 'inpt1')
    {
        clearTimeout(queue);
        queue = setTimeout(runDefault, 500);
    }
    else if(elem.id == 'btn1')
    {
        clearTimeout(queue);
        runButton1();
    }
    else
    {
        clearTimeout(queue);
        runButton2();
    }
}

function runDefault()
{
    alert('default');
}

function runButton1()
{
    alert('Button 1');   
}

function runButton2()
{
    alert('Button 2');   
}
```

and only changed that all listeners point to the same controlling function:

```
<input type="text" id="inpt1" onblur="checkInput(this);" />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="checkInput(this);" />
<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="checkInput(this);" />
```

It is basically setting the callback function in a timeout queue and having each listener wipe the queue. 500ms is long enough for any events to clear, but yes, it is still a point of unreliability. Maybe it is within a tolerable threshold for you though. You decide.

*updated to adjust for OP's comment about queueing button 1 and 2

Comment: Thanks! 500ms is probably long enough, and it's obviously something we can fiddle with based on testing and feedback.

Comment: Just as a question - if the user clicked button 1 or two, is there still a need for the timer? Or would it be safe to replace those lines with runButton1() and runButton2() respectively, after clearing the timeout?

Comment: no, there's no need for the timer in those cases. just the clearTimeout. that's the key part here. I just copy/pasted but that's a good call.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using jQuery

```
$("#btn1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('button 1 clicked');
});

$("#btn2").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
 alert('button 2 clicked');
});
// you may want to use blur event, rather than change event
$("#inpt1").change(function(){
     alert('no button was clicked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/habo/ukz37ztc/1/

Comment: im guessing you got downvoted cause you just threw out some jquery and called it done. OP didn't specify jquery, nor does it look like this would do anything for his problem.

Comment: It doesn't work - if I enter some text and click the first button, I get the change() function, which is the exact opposite of what I want to have happen.

Comment: @Elie can you elaborate what you want. When user enters some value in text box and click btn1 or btn2 you want those button events to fire, and when do you want the textbox change event fire?

Answer (score 0):

I'd set it up a little different. Using jQuery:

```
$('#inpt1').change(function(event){ 
alert('change event');
});

$('#btn1').click(function(event){ 
    alert('button 1 click');
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#btn2').click(function(event){ 
    alert('button 2 click');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="inpt1" name="inpt1" />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" value="Submit" />
<input type="submit" id="btn2" value="Submit" />
```

Also, the change() event for your text input is only going to fire after the user leaves the input (blur). If you want to track a change, [I might suggest keypress or keydown event.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310647/why-keydown-event-works-like-keypress-event)

Hope this helps!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re5ewdba/)

Comment: `keypress` or `keydown` won't work for mobile. Better to use `input`.

Comment: Actually, leaving the input is exactly when I want to fire the event, so change is fine. Going to try this out, thanks!

Comment: I'd try attaching a blur() event then rather than change(). In my experience, change() is used for select input types.

Comment: So it seems that the blur() and onchange() are getting called first. How do I invert the order (or see if the button was clicked, and then just fall through)?

Comment: If all you are trying to do is check the input, I would remove the button click events and roll with just a blur() event. http://jsfiddle.net/jovnch5o/1/